# django error: "asc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nulls_last' "

Tags: python, django

```
class CustomOrderFilter(OrderingFilter):
allowed_custom_filters = ['target_item__type_service', 'target_item__level', 'target_item__room__name',
                          'client__user_full_name', 'designer__user_full_name', 'status', 'date_due_decorist',
                          'target_item__date_answered']

def get_ordering(self, request, queryset, view):
    params = request.query_params.get(self.ordering_param)
    if params:
        fields = [param.strip() for param in params.split(',')]
        ordering = [f for f in fields if f.lstrip('-') in self.allowed_custom_filters]
        if ordering:
            return ordering

    return self.get_default_ordering(view)

def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
    order_fields = []
    ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)
    if not ordering:
        return queryset
    order_fields.append(ordering[0])

    if 'status' in order_fields or '-status' in order_fields:
        ids = [0, 1, 2, 18, 3, 6, 9, 7, 21, 5, 8, 11, 12, 10, 14, 15, 16, 20, 4, 13, 17]
        rev_ids = [11, 8, 5, 21, 7, 9, 6, 3, 18, 2, 1, 0, 12, 10, 14, 15, 16, 20, 4, 13, 17]
        if '-status' in order_fields:
            order = Case(*[When(status=id, then=pos) for pos, id in enumerate(rev_ids)])
        else:
            order = Case(*[When(status=id, then=pos) for pos, id in enumerate(ids)])
        return queryset.order_by(order)

    if '-date_due_decorist' in order_fields:
        return queryset.order_by(F('date_due_decorist').desc(nulls_last=True))

    elif 'date_due_decorist' in order_fields:
        return queryset.order_by(F('date_due_decorist').asc(nulls_last=True))

    return queryset.order_by(ordering[0])
```

In custom ordering django, I am getting error as "**asc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nulls_last'** ". I want to show null values always at last in date_due_decorist column while sorting. Please let me know if **django version 1.10** supports 'nulls_last' or not.
If not support then let me know how can this be done?

Comment: nulls_last was added in Django 1.11. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#models. If possible consider upgrading to 1.11. Django 1.10 in unsupported for almost 5 years now.

Comment: @BartoszStasiak Actually whole application is based on Django 1.10, so can't upgrade it. Cant we done any other way apart from 'nulls_last' ?

Comment: IDK. Maybe you can query them separetly, convert to lists and then join together, but I don't know really.